# How to move values stored in variables to the left with the first value to move to the back

Tags: python

I have 4 variables (1,2,3,4) and I have to write a Python code to move the values stored in those variables to the left, with the leftmost value ending up in the rightmost variable
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjAtG.png)

Comment: Great. What did you try so far?

Comment: Read about list slicing. Use it with for loop.

Comment: Please consider validating one of the proposed answer if you considered it useful ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new list and copy values at the right place:

```
previous_list = [1,2,3,4]
new_list = []

for i in range(1, len(previous_list)):
    new_list.append(previous_list[i])

new_list.append(previous_list[0])

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lis = [1,2,3,4]

lis = lis[1:] + [lis[0]]
```

A good description of slicing can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
x=[1,2,3,4]

y=(x+x)[1:len(x)+1]
print(y)
```

Output:

```py
[2, 3, 4, 1]

[Program finished]
```

Comment: I would be interested to know how this works exactly

Comment: ```(x+x)``` duplicates ```x``` so we have: ```[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]``` then iterating from 1 till 5 (```len(X)+1```) returns 3 elements from first ```x``` and 1 from the second.

Comment: I get it ! Interesting way of solving the problem